# how to get Images from xmpp in android application

Tags: android

I am working on android contacts application. I use XMPP to get the buddy name, status. I need to get the buddy image. How can i achieve that? I am using custom adapter to display the contents. Kindly guide me in dislaying user image from xmpp in list.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to get all buddy info

```
Roster roster = XMPPConnection.getRoster();
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries= roster.getEntries();
            ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                    new VCardProvider());
            VCard card = null;
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                card = new VCard();
                Presence presencek= roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                try {
                    card.load(Main.conn, entry.getUser());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String jid = entry.getUser();
                 String name = card.getField("FN");
                String status = presencek.getType().name();
                Log.d("Prescence", "" + presencek.getType().name());// //num one log

                byte[] imgs = card.getAvatar();
                if (imgs != null) {
                    int len = imgs.length;
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgs, 0, len);
                }
```

Comment: From your code i'm getting the status as Available or Unavailble, how can i get the busy and away states.